# Prolog Query: Return value based on Facts

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog as a whole and i am learning prolog query.

I am looking at this tutorial. 
http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc352/notes/prolog/factsrules.html
and trying to play around with my own database.

```
Person("Mike", "123456").   //Person(Name,ID)
Info("CA", "123456", "17"). //Info(State, ID, Age)
```

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to return someone's age by their name and State.
by doing the following query, this should return 17.

```
Age_Of(Name, State, N) :- Info(State, Person(Name, X), N).
```

i tried the above code and it returns "No". I believe that it is still evaluate as boolean. However, I want the function to return the actual age.

Comment: (to your new, deleted Q) `is_older` would more truly be named `twice_older`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's point some facts:

- You should write your database of facts without using a capital letter as first letter. So `Person("Mike", "123456").` should be `person("Mike", "123456").` and `Info("CA", "123456", "17").` should be `info("CA", "123456", "17").`
- In prolog there are not functions but only predicates and should be defined aswell using non capital letter, so `Age_Of(Name, State, N)` should be `age_of(Name, State, N).`
- Even if you remove all first capital letter, you get `Singleton variables: [X]` while you execute the code. This mean that you dhave defined a variable, in this case X, but not used anywhere. In this case, you should replace every singleton variable with `_` or add `_` before the variable (`_X` in this case).

To solve your problem, this is the solution:

```
person("Mike", "123456").   % person(Name,ID)
info("CA", "123456", "17"). % info(State, ID, Age)


age_of(Name, State, Age):-
   person(Name,ID),
   info(State, ID, Age).
```

So first you have to find the ID of a person with a given name and then find the corresponding age. Query:

```
?- age_of(Name,State,Age).
Age = "17",
Name = "Mike",
State = "CA"
```

This query is quite generic, you can be more specific (for instance, specifing a name). Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to only return the age from the above facts?

Comment: my goal is to return the age withou first knowing it. I wan to return age based on name and state.  Otherwise it defeats the purpose of my code.

Comment: `?- age_of(Name,"CA",Age).` `Age = "17"`, `Name = "Mike"`.